# Using babel and cleveref causes unnecessary horizontal space in header

Tags: spacing, babel, cleveref

### **Update**

This bug has been fixed with version 0.18.9 of `cleveref`, which is currently on `ctan`.

### **Question**

`Babel` and `cleveref` do not seem to work flawlessy together when they share the same language option. In the MWE, the output of `Some text\leftmark` in the main text should be equal to *Some text1 Chapter*, but there is an extra space in front of *1 Chapter*. In the header, this has the effect that its text is not inline with the body text. Interestingly, this problem disappears when babel uses another language option, eg. `english`.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\clearpage
\noindent Some text\leftmark
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a bug in `cleveref`. If I change line 4516 of `cleveref.sty` from

```
4516   \PackageInfo{cleveref}{loaded `spanish' language definitions}
```

into

```
4516   \PackageInfo{cleveref}{loaded `spanish' language definitions}%
```

the space disappears.

This is common with all the other languages and should require a bug fix.

---

As a temporary workaround you can say

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \patchcmd{\extrasspanish}
    {\PackageInfo {cleveref}{loaded `spanish' language definitions} }
    {\PackageInfo {cleveref}{loaded `spanish' language definitions}}
    {}{}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\clearpage

\noindent Some text\leftmark

\end{document}
```

---

**Really minimal example**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
X\foreignlanguage{spanish}{X}X
\end{document}
```

The output, without the correction, is

> X XX

With the correction it is

> XXX

Comment: Thanks for the quick help egreg. I am going to report the author this bug, if you haven't already done so.

Comment: @maetra Please, do.

Comment: According to the author, this bug should be fixed in the next release of cleveref.